# Empty XPath result when it shouldn't be

Tags: php, xpath

I have the following simple html:

```
<span class="myClass">
  <strong>Number</strong>
  : 9
</span>
```

I simply want to parse this to return: `: 9`

I'm trying the following XPath which i'm pretty sure is correct but I'm not getting any text returned:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHtml($htmlAsAbove);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$result = $xpath->query("normalize-space(//span/text()[last()])");

if($result->length > 0) {
  echo 'here it is '.$result->item(0);
} else {
  echo 'nothing'; // this returns every time
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing wrong with your xpath, only [`DOMXPath::query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php) unable to return other than node-set. For executing xpath expression that doesn't return node-set*, use [`DOMXPath::evaluate()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.evaluate.php) instead :

```
$result = $xpath->evaluate("normalize-space(//span/text()[last()])");
echo 'here it is '.$result;
```

*: xpath [`normalize-space()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-normalize-space) function returns `string`

**<kbd>[eval.in Demo](https://eval.in/380975)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
here it is : 9
```

Comment: Aaaahhhhh - did now know that - much appreciated